# How to type the initial state for react context when using useState as value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I recently saw a youtube video by Jack Herrington, "Mastering React Context" where he used `useState` as a value for his context provider. This struck me as interesting but when i tried doing the same with typescript i was stumped completely by how to type the initial state.

Example JS code:

```
const CounterContext = createContext(null);

const CounterContextProvider = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <CounterContext.Provider value={useState(0)}>
      {children}
    </CounterContext.Provider>
}
```

Using `null` as default value is out of the question. I could define the correct types for `useState` but what would the initial state values look like?

Comment: What about `const [someValue, setValue] = useState<number>(0);` ?

Comment: @guimauve, check the answer bellow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value returned by `useState(0)` is a tuple of type `[number, Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>]`, where `Dispatch` and `SetStateAction` are imported from react. So with a mock default value, that will look like:

```
import { createContext, Dispatch, SetStateAction } from "react";

const CounterContext = createContext<
  [number, Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>]
>([0, () => {}]);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I never occurred to me that `() => {}` could be a default value. Thanks.